# Get Value From input and replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have many a href tags and also i have input with type hidden.
i wrote a code to get the value of closest input to each a href then put the value of that input instead of data-page and the text of the a tag.
i wrote the below code but it is not work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".PageNumber").each(function(index, element) {
    var pagenum = $(this).closest('.page').val();  
    var linkk = $(this).attr("data-page");
 var linktext = $(this).text();
    $(this).attr(pagenum);
 $(this).text(pagenum);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="PageNumber" data-page="" data-href="home.htm">1</a> 
<input type="hidden" value="1" class="page"/> 
<a class="PageNumber" data-page="" data-href="home2.htm">1</a> 
<input type="hidden" value="2" class="page"/> 
<a class="PageNumber" data-page="" data-href="home3.htm">1</a> 
<input type="hidden" value="3" class="page"/>
```

Comment: `jQuery.closest` does not work as you expected. It doesn't search through element siblings.

Comment: You better use the `jQuery.next()` function to get the next input.

Comment: Explain me the output that you want to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want to do in the clearest way ^^

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".PageNumber").each(function(index, element) {
    var pagenum = $(this).next('.page').val();  
    $(this).attr("data-page", pagenum);
    $(this).text(pagenum);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="PageNumber" data-page="" data-href="home.htm">1</a> 
<input type="hidden" value="1" class="page"/> 
<a class="PageNumber" data-page="" data-href="home2.htm">1</a> 
<input type="hidden" value="2" class="page"/> 
<a class="PageNumber" data-page="" data-href="home3.htm">1</a> 
<input type="hidden" value="3" class="page"/>
```

Comment: np, i like to help

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.closest()` is not what you want. this function will find the closest parent element that matches the selector, starting with the current element. https://api.jquery.com/closest/

You better use the `jQuery.next()` function to get the next input. https://api.jquery.com/next/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".PageNumber").each(function(index, element) {
    var pagenum = $(this).next('.page').val();
    var linkk = $(this).attr("data-page");
    var linktext = $(this).text();
    $(this).attr(pagenum);
    $(this).text(pagenum);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="PageNumber" data-page="" data-href="home.htm">1</a>
<input type="hidden" value="1" class="page" />
<a class="PageNumber" data-page="" data-href="home2.htm">1</a>
<input type="hidden" value="2" class="page" />
<a class="PageNumber" data-page="" data-href="home3.htm">1</a>
<input type="hidden" value="3" class="page" />
```

Comment: how can i set the value to data-page too?

Comment: `jQuery.attr()` is used to get and set attributes. `jQuery.attr('data-page')` will get the attribute and `jQuery.attr('data-page', value)` will set the attribute. You can also use the `jQuery.data()` function. https://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `closest` function doesn't do what you need it to do.
Here is its description.

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

You could use `next` to get the input, here is an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".PageNumber").each(function(index, element) {
    var pagenum = $(this).next('.page').val();
    $(this).data("page", pagenum)
    $(this).text(pagenum);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="PageNumber" data-page="" data-href="home.htm">1</a> 
<input type="hidden" value="1" class="page"/> 
<a class="PageNumber" data-page="" data-href="home2.htm">1</a> 
<input type="hidden" value="2" class="page"/> 
<a class="PageNumber" data-page="" data-href="home3.htm">1</a> 
<input type="hidden" value="3" class="page"/>
```

Comment: how can i set the value to data-page too?

Comment: your editet answer is not replace with value of input for each data-href

Comment: @Inaz I'm not sure what you mean, if you want to change the `a` element's `data-href` property you can do the same thing as I've done for the `data-page` property.